# Passing %F to terminal application in .desktop launcher

Tags: command-line, gnome, launcher, .desktop, console

Some console editors can open multiple files at ones - for example

```
nano file1 file2
```

will launch nano with two "tabs".

But `.desktop` launcher with

```
Terminal=true
Exec=nano %F
```

will open two console windows with two instances of nano, each with one single file opened.

How to make `.desktop` pass multiple files to single-instance console application as parameters? Preferably as one-liner which can be used in `Exec=...` field of `.desktop` file.

**Update:**
This behaviour tends to be gnome-specific, in KDE it "just works" with:

```
Exec=nano %F
```

Comment: How exactly you're opening the two files ? Drag and drop over the `.desktop` file ? I normally don't use `%F` in my `.desktop` files so need to understand how you're using that

Comment: Try to wrap it in shell, like `Exec=bash -c 'nano "$@" ' sh %F` . If they're passed as one string, this may work, although I suspect issues with files that contain spaces in the filenames

Comment: I open file selecting them in Nautilus and pressing "open with...". Solution with `Exec=bash -c 'nano "$@" ' sh %F` doesn't work, it launches two console windows.

Comment: @Narcial OK, I'll play with it tomorrow, maybe I'll figure this out. Interesting question

Comment: I updated my question up there - in KDE it works with Exec=nano %F so it looks like a bug

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/117). Opening a bunch of files with "open with another app" works totally different then opening them in default app.
(can't accept my own answer for a while)