# Gnome desktop entry not working?

Tags: gnome, launcher, vlc, file-association

when I select two video files and open them through the Files manager, it opens two vlc instances, even though I have `/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U` in `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop` (see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) for the meaning of %U). Is this a known bug in Ubuntu 18.04 ? (it worked in Ubuntu 16.04). How to fix it ?

Note: I still want to be able to open multiple instances of vlc when I open I click on 2 files two times instead of selecting two files, so the option in vlc to open only one instance when opened from file manager doesn't apply here.

Comment: Yep, that's a bug, specifically: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/117 As referenced in duplicate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing %F to terminal application in .desktop launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073254/passing-f-to-terminal-application-in-desktop-launcher)